# How to resolve NoSuchElementException in Selenium with java?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, exception

CODE:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("USER")).sendKeys("XYZ");
driver.findElement(By.name("PASSWORD")).sendKeys("abc");
```

I have tried various ways not just name but by xpath, css selectors but every time the error remained same. While inspecting the elements the below is the result. As seen in other answers it is not in iframe. I have also tried putting a wait statement but no luck.

HTML:

```
<input class="news" name="USER" value="" size="13" style="width:100%;">
<input class="news" name="PASSWORD" value="" size="13" style="width:100%;" 
type="password">
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to 
locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"USER"}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, sometimes it happen if the page is not properly at the time of searching the element.  Try this      
PageFactory.initElements(driver, "class name".class);

Refer this page. It will give you a proper idea 
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-pattern-model-page-factory/

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: use explicit wait statement and try

Comment: @joe I have tried that way as well but that too isn't working.

Comment: its better if you have given the code. I had same problem. Have tried using "PageFactory.initElements"?
Take this for an example
GoogleSearchPage page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);

Comment: Related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons.

1. Page not correctly loaded at the time. To resolve this `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` you can add page load timeout.
2. Element is not actually visible in screen and you need to scroll down or scroll up to that element

   ```
   public void scrollDown(){
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
   }
   ```
3. Another solution is Add time to wait until element visible

   ```
   public WebElement waitUntilElementVisible(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int delay) {
       try{
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, delay);
           return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
       }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
           throw new RuntimeException("Web element not visible within given time" + element +" Time "+ delay);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net `ISearchContext.FindElement()` throws `NoSuchElementException`. Based on the [official Selenium documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) I speculate that in Java it does not throw exception or `WebDriverWait.Until` knows how to handle it.

`WebDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));` would help but it [does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721303/ignoreexceptiontypes-does-not-work-c-webdriver/41307948).

Solved with static helper method:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
namespace Blah
{
    public static class SearchContextHelper
    {
        public static IWebElement TryFindElement(this ISearchContext searchContext, By by)
        {
            try { return searchContext.FindElement(by); }
            catch (NoSuchElementException) { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :
`selenium.waitForPageToLoad(PAGE_TO_LOAD_TIMEOUT);`

Comment: Since this is a new answer to an old question with several other answers, could you please expand on your answer to explain how it improves on the existing answers?

Answer (score -1):

If page will be not loaded properly then it might be this kind of error will be occur 
Please try with this:

```java
WebElement username=driver.findelement(By.name("USER"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
username.sendkeys("test");

WebElement username=driver.findelement(By.name("PASSWORD"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
username.sendkeys("test");
```